# How to detect if entity exist in database

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity-relationship

I have 2 entities, User and Profile. Profile has in-symfony relation with User, but there is no in-database relation (no foreign key, no cascade) - only simple int column named user_id and nothing more.

Problem is obvious: when i delete user - associated profiles persists, but their user_id points to non-existing user row.

Since I use in-symfony relations when i fetch profile from database it fetches also related user entity. I expected that if there is no row with specific ID, it would just leave null or at least throw an exception or something.

Problem is that symfony creates empty User entity object with only id set. rest of its fields are null.

I know solution would be to create FK, constraints etc ... but I'm not allowed to touch anything in database schema.

How can I manage this problem ? I could even leave those empty object if only i had simple way to determine if they exist in database inside TWIG - so i would know if i can display {{ profile.user.email }} for example.

Comment: Fast solution: there's some field that is mandatory onto db and that new user entity doesn't has value (null)? If so, just check for them

Comment: thought about that but would rather have more solid and generic solution

Comment: I suppose that's solid enaugh: db will never let you persist an object with a null value if you set proper constraints. That way you're 100% safe from errors (at least nothing came in my mind that could put at risk this mechanism)

Comment: As I said - i cannot modify anything in database, that includes putting constraints. Yeah - i know, it sucks but not my choice.

Comment: So DB hasn't any constraint in any field that you could take advantage of to recognize if user object is a new one or a db one?

Comment: Well, it has, but to be defensive - I cannot relay on something that I have no control on. I have to assume some day someone may remove those constraints (dont ask me why - i dont know why people do stupid things, but im sure they do). In such situation we have worst scenario ever - it doesn't crash, no exceptions thrown, but with time database grows with rubbish rows and nobody is aware of that - till time someone says "hey, why this run so slow ?!"

Comment: You have a good point but if you can't modify DB it's very hard to reach some stability over future "stupid" changes to db schema

Comment: Its even worse - I cannot check profile.user.email for being null without haveing EntityNotFound exception thrown ... when I do any call to uninitialized property of this empty entity, doctrine tries to fetch it, and since there is no row with provided ID, it throws exception ...

Comment: Good example that shows how bad Symfony/Doctrine is when it comes to smart and clean usability. Laravel does this via `Car::findById(17)->exist();`, Symfony needs big fat workarounds...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution: its fetch: EAGER set to problematic mapping in doctrine.

By default doctrine uses LAZY fetching what results in using Proxy classes generated by doctrine for related entity. That class is almost same as real entity class. Difference is inside getter methods that before returning value performs fetching entity from database.

At this point, when you call getter on such proxy, doctrine tries to find entity in database using its ID, and since it doesn't find anything it throws exception.

When using EAGER fetching doctrine performs fetching of related entities on the same time when it fetches main entity and if it doesn't find it then sets null on relation field.

Answer (score 0):

Fast and dirty solution, as you ask, is to use this test: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/defined.html
But I strongly recommend to rework your entity relations.

Comment: Nope, it checks whether variable is defined, not if entity object has its representation in database.

Comment: Ok, so {% profile.user.email is defined %} is not enough?